# How to create an image upload product attribute in magento?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I know to create new product attribute in magento by **catalag->manage attributes**. By the same way i have created an image upload product attribute.It was suceessfully created and also i have added this attribute to default attribute set.

But that image upload attribute doesn't show on product creation page.(Text,Yes/No,etc...I got these kind attributes)

I have searched a lot regarding this issue. I can't find how to reslove this issue. Please save me guys

Comment: the product you're trying to create, is it of default attribute set type?

Comment: @OSdave yes i have added that attribute under default attribute set type.

Comment: you're not answering my question...

Comment: i have default attribute set type only

Comment: magento version? did you flush the cache? indexes?

Comment: version 1.7 yeah i have cleared both cache and index. still now i didn't get

Comment: indeed, this is a bug of Magento. you should report it to magentocommerce